# CloudWatch agent is not configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have successfully installed CloudWatch agent on my EC2 instance where we are using Apache2.

After configuring my `config.json` file when I am restarting the CloudWatch agent it showing error:

> amazon-cloudwatch-agent is not configured. Applying amazon-cloudwatch-agent default configuration.

and creating the default `cloud-watch-agent.toml` file. When I am editing it manually and again restarting the CloudWatch agent `cloud-watch-agent.toml` file again reset to its default value.

How to overcome this problem?

[image: Log file]

Answer (score 0):

TOML file contains the converted contents of the JSON configuration file. We should not directly modify this file. It can be used to verify that JSON to TOML translation was successful.

When you modify the agent configuration file manually, use the `fetch-config` command to start the agent to ensure that the agent reflects your changes. Refer this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html#start-CloudWatch-Agent-EC2-commands-fleet).